# UIBezierPath Subclass Initializer

Tags: ios, swift, inheritance, subclass, uibezierpath

I'm trying to create a subclass of UIBezierPath to add some properties that are useful to me.

```
class MyUIBezierPath : UIBezierPath {
   var selectedForLazo : Bool! = false

   override init(){
       super.init()
   }

   /* Compile Error: Must call a designated initializer of the superclass 'UIBezierPath' */
   init(rect: CGRect){
       super.init(rect: rect)
   }

   /* Compile Error: Must call a designated initializer of the superclass 'UIBezierPath' */
   init(roundedRect: CGRect, cornerRadius: CGFloat) {
       super.init(roundedRect: roundedRect, cornerRadius: cornerRadius)
   }

   required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
       fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
   }
}
```

EDIT:
I need this because in my code i write

```
var path = MyUIBezierPath(roundedRect: rect, cornerRadius: 7)
```

and it results in a compile error:

"Must call a designated initializer of the superclass 'UIBezierPath'"

I tried to add that initializers in the subclass but it seems not to work.

Can you help me please?

Comment: What does "this doesn't work" mean? Get rid of the fatalError line in intWithCoder, and replace it with a call to super.

Comment: I think you only need to implement initWithCoder:. Add a call to super in that one, and delete the others.

Comment: OK, I'll ask again. What does "does't work" mean? That is completely useless to someone trying to help you. You need to say what did happen. Does it not compile? Does it crash when you run? What? Be specific.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**NOTE**: This problem is solved in iOS 9, where the API has been rewritten so that `init(rect:)` exists, and so do all the others, as convenience initializers, as they should be.

---

### The Problem

In a nutshell, the problem you're experiencing is that the following code does not compile:

```
    class MyBezierPath : UIBezierPath {}
    let b = MyBezierPath(rect:CGRectZero)
```

From the Swift point of view, that seems just wrong. The documentation appears to say that UIBezierPath has an initializer `init(rect:)`. But then why isn't UIBezierPath's `init(rect:)` being inherited in our subclass MyBezierPath? According to the normal rules of initializer inheritance, it should be.

### The Explanation

UIBezierPath is not intended for subclassing. Accordingly, it doesn't have any initializers - except for `init()`, which it inherits from NSObject. In Swift, UIBezierPath *looks* as if it has initializers; but this is a false representation. What UIBezierPath actually has, as we can see if we look at the Objective-C headers, are convenience constructors, which are class methods, such as this:

```
+ (UIBezierPath *)bezierPathWithRect:(CGRect)rect;
```

Now, this method (along with its siblings) demonstrates some unusual features that Swift does not deal with very well:

- It is not merely a variant of an initializer; it is a *pure* convenience constructor. Objective-C shows us that UIBezierPath has no corresponding true initializer `initWithRect:`. That's a very unusual situation in Cocoa.
- It returns `UIBezierPath*`, not `instancetype`. This means that it cannot be inherited, because it returns an instance of the wrong type. In a subclass MyBezierPath, calling `bezierPathWithRect:` yields a UIBezierPath, *not* a MyBezierPath.

Swift copes badly with this situation. On the one hand, it translates the class method `bezierPathWithRect:` into an apparent initializer `init(rect:)`, in accordance with its usual policy. But on the other hand, this is not a "real" initializer, and cannot be inherited by a subclass.

You have thus been misled by the apparent initializer `init(rect:)` and then surprised and stumped when you could not call it on your subclass because it isn't inherited.

**NOTE:** I'm not saying that Swift's behavior here is not a bug; I think it *is* a bug (though I'm a little hazy on whether to blame the bug on Swift or on the UIBezierPath API). Either Swift should not turn `bezierPathWithRect:` into an initializer, or, if it *does* make it an initializer, it should make that initializer inheritable. Either way, it *should* be inheritable. But it isn't, so now we have to look for a workaround.

### Solutions

So what should you do? I have two solutions:

- **Don't subclass.** Subclassing UIBezierPath was a bad idea to start with. It is not made for this sort of thing. Instead of a subclass, make a *wrapper* - a class or struct that, rather than having the feature that *is* a UIBezierPath, has the feature that it *has* a UIBezierPath. Let's call it MyBezierPathWrapper:

  ```
  struct MyBezierPathWrapper {
      var selectedForLazo : Bool = false
      var bezierPath : UIBezierPath!
  }
  ```

  This simply couples your custom properties and methods with a normal UIBezierPath. You could then create it in two steps, like this:

  ```
  var b = MyBezierPathWrapper()
  b.bezierPath = UIBezierPath(rect:CGRectZero)
  ```

  If that feels unsatisfactory, you can make this a one-step creation by adding an initializer that takes the UIBezierPath:

  ```
  struct MyBezierPathWrapper {
      var selectedForLazo : Bool = false
      var bezierPath : UIBezierPath
      init(_ bezierPath:UIBezierPath) {
          self.bezierPath = bezierPath
      }
  }
  ```

  And now you can create it like this:

  ```
  var b = MyBezierPathWrapper(UIBezierPath(rect:CGRectZero))
  ```
- **Subclass with a convenience constructor.** If you insist on subclassing, even though UIBezierPath is not intended for that sort of thing, you can do it by supplying a convenience constructor. This works because the only important thing about a UIBezierPath is its `CGPath`, so you can make this convenience constructor a *copy* constructor merely transferring the path from a real UIBezierPath:

  ```
  class MyBezierPath : UIBezierPath {
      var selectedForLazo : Bool! = false
      convenience init(path:UIBezierPath) {
          self.init()
          self.CGPath = path.CGPath
      }
  }
  ```

  Now we can create one very similarly to the previous approach:

  ```
  let b = MyBezierPath(path:UIBezierPath(rect:CGRectZero))
  ```

  It isn't great, but I think it's marginally more satisfying than having to redefine *all* the initializers as your solution does. In the end I'm really doing exactly the same thing you're doing, in a more compressed way. But on balance I prefer the first solution: don't subclass in the first place.

Comment: Thank you matt for your answer, i found strange that init(rect:) wasn't a designated initializer but a convenience one, and i came to the same conclusion. I'll follow your suggestion and i will report the bug.
I apologize not to have explained the problem better before, and thank you for your elegant solution.

Comment: It has nothing to do with designated vs. convenience initializers. It has to do with inheritance. I've expanded my answer to explain more fully, and to provide a better solution.

Comment: Note that in iOS 9 this problem is solved; the API has been tweaked so that `init(rect:)` exists, and so do all the others, as convenience initializers, as they should be.

Answer (score 0):

I found this simple workaround that seems to do its job.

```
class MyUIBezierPath : UIBezierPath {
   var selectedForLazo : Bool! = false

   override init() {
       super.init()
   }

   init(rect: CGRect){
       super.init()
       self.appendPath(UIBezierPath(rect: rect))
   }

   init(roundedRect: CGRect, cornerRadius: CGFloat) {
       super.init()
       self.appendPath(UIBezierPath(roundedRect: roundedRect, cornerRadius: cornerRadius))
   }

   required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
       super.init()
   }
}
```

Please post other solutions because they'll surely be better than mine.