# Subclass in Swift does not inherit initialiser of its superclass

Tags: ios, macos, swift, inheritance, swift2

I have stumbled upon a very strange issue when trying to subclass `NSBezierPath`.

Below is the definition of my subclass:

```
class OSBezierPath: NSBezierPath {
        
    func addLineToPoint(point:CGPoint) {
        self.lineToPoint(point)
    }
}
```

This subclass works apart from the fact that I cannot access some of the initialisers of the `NSBezierPath`. For example, line below is invalid:

```
let path = OSBezierPath(ovalInRect: rect)
```

Compiler throws an error

> Extra argument 'ovalInRect' in call

## Cause of this bug

Cause of this bug is well-explained in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29867782/uibezierpath-subclass-initalizer). However, the suggested answer doesn't work well for me because what I am trying to achieve is to use `OSBezierPath` on both iOS and Mac OS.

My original code read like this:

```
#if os(iOS)
    typealias OSBezierPath = UIBezierPath
#else
    class OSBezierPath: NSBezierPath {
        
        func addLineToPoint(point:CGPoint) {
            self.lineToPoint(point)
        }
    }
#endif
```

This code doesn't work, but I have found 2 workarounds which are more elegant for my purpose than the suggested answer in another question.

Comment: Same issue as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29867782/uibezierpath-subclass-initalizer, despite the difference between UI and NS. And the real solution is the same: update to Xcode 7 beta, where the API is mended.

Comment: Firstly, thanks a lot for showing that question! Secondly, I am using Xcode 7 beta - still no luck.

Comment: I didn't actually check the situation for NSBezierPath, so I could be wrong. But in Xcode 7, UIBezierPath is subclassable - the class functions have been turned into proper initializers and are inherited.

Comment: Yes, they were for UIBezierPath. Not for NSBezierPath though. However, as I now know that what I am experiencing is not a REAL bug I have two ways of achieving what I want. Approaches which you suggested will certainly work, but if you check the "P.S." section you will see that they are not very elegant for my case. I will post an answer now with two other approaches which work

Comment: @matt please reopen the question so that I can add 2 workarounds which work better for case of iOS/Mac portability :)

Comment: Sure, why not? Glad you worked it out.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I now posted my answer. Would take ages to figure this out without your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## 1st solution

This solution uses extension to add a function to `NSBezierPath` which will allow it to draw lines in the same way as `UIBezierPath`.

```
#if os(iOS)
    typealias OSBezierPath = UIBezierPath
#else
    typealias OSBezierPath = NSBezierPath
    
    extension OSBezierPath {
        func addLineToPoint(point:CGPoint) {
            self.lineToPoint(point)
        }
    }
#endif
```

This avoids any potential bug because there is no subclassing involved. Therefore, line below:

```
let path = OSBezierPath(ovalInRect: rect)
```

actually translates to:

```
let path = NSBezierPath(ovalInRect: rect)
```

and so compiler is happy :)

## 2nd solution (Xcode 7)

Second solution uses the fact that class functions of `UIBezierPath` were converted to proper initialisers in Xcode 7. So, code below will work:

```
#if os(iOS)
    class OSBezierPath: UIBezierPath {
        func lineToPoint(point:CGPoint) {
            self.addLineToPoint(point)
        }
    }
#else
    typealias OSBezierPath = NSBezierPath
#endif
```

This allows us to use `OSBezierPath` by calling `lineToPoint` on both iOS and Mac OS.