# Swift 'final' subclass vs extension performance with whole module optimisation

Tags: ios, macos, inheritance, swift2

I am now working on an app which I want to ship on both iOS and Mac OS. Due to this I started looking at ways in which I can reuse as much code as I can.

I recently ran into a [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31822834/subclass-in-swift-does-not-inherit-initialiser-of-its-superclass) from which I had two ways out - either create an extension or a subclass.

My objective was to create typealias/class called `OSBezierPath` which would allow me to share a lot of drawing code between iOS and Mac OS. My app's drawing code was simple so I only had to ensure that line drawings can be called in the same way on iOS and Mac OS.

`NSBezierPath` path cannot be reliably subclassed. Accepted answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29867782/uibezierpath-subclass-initalizer) question explains why this is the case. It deals with `UIBezierPath` but `NSBezierPath` has the same problems and, unlike for `UIBezierPath`, those are not fixed in Xcode 7.

I came up with two ways of achieving what I want.

## Using extension

```
#if os(iOS)
    typealias OSBezierPath = UIBezierPath
#else
    typealias OSBezierPath = NSBezierPath

    extension OSBezierPath {
        func addLineToPoint(point:CGPoint) {
            self.lineToPoint(point)
        }
    }
#endif
```

With this code I can use function `addLineToPoint` on both iOS and Mac OS. However, since `UIBezierPath` can be subclassed starting from Xcode 7 I also have another option.

## Using subclass

```
#if os(iOS)
    final class OSBezierPath: UIBezierPath {
        func lineToPoint(point:CGPoint) {
            self.addLineToPoint(point)
        }
    }
#else
    typealias OSBezierPath = NSBezierPath
#endif
```

With this code I can use `lineToPoint` on both iOS and Mac OS.

## Question

In my case it doesn't matter which approach to choose. However, I am wondering about performance issues.

Since whole module optimisation is able to do a lot of magic with subclasses that are defined with `final` keyword does it mean that subclassing approach will be better from the point of view of performance?

Comment: I think you are over engineering a non exist problem. Do you have any performance issue? If you don't, pick whatever way you like. If you do, profile it to find out the bottleneck. I don't think these will ever make noticeable performance difference specially Swift compiler are improving and new optimisations will be added in later releases.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I do not have any issues (my example is very trivial). However, I wonder which approach is better in general. It is not difficult to imagine a more complex scenario (for example when you need to add lots of different functions). Which approach will be faster in that case?

Comment: As I said, for complex (or simple) scenario, you have to profile first in order to solve (and prove existence) any performance issue. You question is more of a style problem to me because the performance difference is so small that can be ignored in most of the cases. The majority of the time used here is the method body, not how the method is called.

Comment: Stylistically both approaches are identical. They are both easy to define and in the rest of the code I will be using OSBezierPath with both of them. Method calling is obviously not a huge overhead. However, it is still an overhead :) Considering that I do not have any preference as to which method to use I want to choose the one which is faster (even if it improves performance by very little). More importantly, I am curious to find out which approach is faster and why. That's the whole point of this question

Comment: OK. Just profile it and you will know the answer (for now). However, the answer may change in future release of Swift.