# How inheritance UIStoryboard

Tags: ios, swift, inheritance, storyboard

How inheritance `UIStoryboard`. I try do custom `UIStoryboard` for incapsulate my vars in it, like this.

```
open class MyStoryboard: UIStoryboard {

    open var connectionRequest: myRosterConnectionRequestsController {
        return get(identifier: "ConnectionRequest")
    }

    open var roster: myRosterController {
        return get(identifier: "Roster")
    }

    open var profile: myProfileController {
        return get(identifier: "Profile")
    }

    override init() {
        super.init(name: "Messenger", bundle: Bundle.my) // <<< this is error
    }

}

extension UIStoryboard {
    open static var myMessanger: MyStoryboard { return MyStoryboard() }

    fileprivate func get<U: UIViewController>(identifier: String) -> U {
        return self.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: identifier) as! U
    }

}
```

But I get Error in init `MyStoryboard`

> Must call a designated initializer of the superclass 'UIStoryboard'

Hoy I can init `MyStoryboard`?
Yes I can `MyStoryboard` as independent class and incapsulate instans of `UIStoryboard`, but I want my class to be inheritance of `UIStoryboard`

Answer (score 0):

**You cannot subclass UIStoryboard class**. The `init(name: String, bundle storyboardBundleOrNil: Bundle?)` is in fact, a static factory method, not an initializer in the Swift meaning.

Take a look at the Objective-C definition.

```
+ (UIStoryboard *)storyboardWithName:(NSString *)name 
                          bundle:(NSBundle *)storyboardBundleOrNil;
```

In this case, there is no initializer you can inherit in your base class. In fact, the designated initializer you should call is the `init()` from `NSObject`.

Here you can find more detailed explanation why it's not possible
https://stackoverflow.com/a/29872355/1692080